# Запуск консоли и формы в одном приложении

Tags: c#

Надо что бы в зависимости от ключей приложения запускалась консоль или Windows.Form. Можно конечно сделать отдельное приложение которое запускает в зависимости от ключей форму или консоль, но может есть решение сделать это в одном приложении?

Comment: напиши bat-файл (bash дял Linux). который будет запускать приложения в зависимости от ключей

Comment: Есть пример на английском стеке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168622/net-program-with-both-winform-and-console-interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример решения:

```
 static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form_Main());
        }
        else if (args[0] == "-console")
        {
            Helper.AllocConsole();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Helper.FreeConsole();
        }
    }
}
public static class Helper
{

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Boolean AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Boolean FreeConsole();
}
```